# SQLITE3 - How to SELECT from table during INSERT on another table using primary key to lookup relevant information

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am attempting to create the below trigger to update the parent invoice record of tblInvoices every time a new item is created under that invoice ID in tblInvoiceItems. The fields being updated are the subtotal, taxes, and total.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tblInvoiceItems_insert AFTER INSERT ON tblInvoiceItems
BEGIN
    INSERT tblInvoices (numberOfItems, subTotal, taxes, total)
    VALUES (numberOfItems + NEW.quanity, subTotal + NEW.charge,
    (SELECT taxRate FROM tblTaxRates WHERE tblInvoiceItems.taxRateID = tbltaxRates.taxRateID)
     * (subTotal + NEW.charge),
    (SELECT taxRate FROM tblTaxRates WHERE tblInvoiceItems.taxRateID = tblTaxRates.taxRateID)
     * (subTotal + NEW.charge) + subTotal + NEW.charge)
    WHERE invoiceID = NEW.invoiceID;
    INSERT INTO tblLogs (affectedObject, userID, eventDescription, eventDescription, dtOccurred) VALUES ("INI" || REPLACE(PRINTF("%8s", NEW.itemID), "0"), 1, "Item added to invoice.", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
END;
```

There error SQLite3 gives me :
Error: near line 1: near "(": syntax error

I cannot for the life of me figure out what the error is or which opening parentheses it is.

Comment: Even if you fix the syntax error, the trigger will not work.  Provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can't combine `INSERT INTO .. VALUES` and `INSERT INTO .. SELECT FROM` construct together which you are currently doing and thus the error. You should change it to below (syntactical) though your `WHERE` makes very little sense `WHERE taxRateID = tblTaxRates.taxRateID` .. not sure why you are joining with same table (doesn't look like a `self join`)

```
INSERT INTO tblInvoices (numberOfItems, subTotal, taxes, total)
SELECT numberOfItems + NEW.quanity, subTotal + NEW.charge,
taxRate ,
taxRate 
FROM tblTaxRates 
WHERE taxRateID = tblTaxRates.taxRateID)
 * (subTotal + NEW.charge) + subTotal + NEW.charge)
AND invoiceID = NEW.invoiceID;
```

Comment: The `INSERT` statements are separate statements within the `TRIGGER`. I read that that was allowed in SQLite3, is it not? The portion `WHERE taxRateID = tblTaxRates.taxRateID` is intended to return the tax rate (percentage of taxation on the purchase) for calculating the taxes, I've updated it to `WHERE tblInvoiceItems.taxRateID = tblTaxRates.taxRateID`. I live in Canada, and we have many different taxes as well as additional taxes for particular types of products. This is intended to apply the appropriate taxation by using the correlating ID.